# How did Murph figure out the identity of her ghost?

Tags: interstellar

I've watched the scene several times now, but I just can't seem to figure out how Murph figured out the identity of her Ghost?

The identity of the ghost is a spoiler:

> The "ghost" was Cooper, her father.

Comment: Related: [How did Murph figure it out?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27029/49)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [screenplay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1623160588) seems to indicate that it was rereading the "STAY" message as an adult that triggered this realization:

> INT. MURPH'S BEDROOM - TWILIGHT
>
> *Murph (forty) picks up the notebook. Opens it. Finds the word* 'STAY' ... *looks up at the books,* REALIZING ...

And then after cutting back to Cooper in the tesseract sending the "STAY" message to the young Murph, it cuts back to the forty-year-old Murph:

> INT. MURPH's BEDROOM - TWILIGHT
>
> *Murph (forty) lowers her notebook, moves to the bookshelves,* IN AWE ...
>
> MURPH Dad ... it was you. You were my ghost ...
>
> *She is crying. Joyful.*

I think it'd be reasonable to conclude it was a sort of "leap of faith" on her part, inspired perhaps by her lifelong grief and her adult sense of how hard it must have been on her father, rather than a conclusion that followed in any completely rational way from the evidence available to her at the time.

Comment: She also indicates that no-one believed her about the watch and thought that she'd made the whole thing up.